# Can an orbital burn and a separate trans-injection burn be combined so that they are perfectly efficient?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

By that, I mean, in general, I'm on the surface of a body, and I want to:

1. Orbit the body, then at some time later
2. Perform an injection burn to intercept another body.

Can these two maneuvers be timed such that the sum of the energies of the burns is equal to a burn that would take the rocket directly from the surface of a body to the intercept trajectory?

When I say "perfect", I mean perfect in theory, not worrying about inefficiencies of restarting engines, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. To get into a sustainable orbit, you need to raise the periapsis, which takes some $\Delta V$ and which does not contribute to escaping. A direct ascent to an escape trajectory doesn't need to raise the periapsis, and so avoids that cost.

However it should be noted that such a "perfect" direct ascent can only be launched from a latitude equal to plus or minus the departure declination. This significantly constrains the set of reachable trajectories for a given launch site, or requires a variable, e.g. ocean-vessel launch site. Going into a parking orbit in order to line up the velocity vector with the outgoing asymptote will, in nearly all cases, reduce the total required $\Delta V$, taking into account the comparatively small cost of raising the periapsis.